# Program for tuition per semester

Tags: python

I am writing a program for tuition. My problem/question is: How can I get the total for just the four years instead of writing out the numbers like I did total+=(8240+8487.20+8741.82+9004.07)*2

```
'''
CPS 313: Assignment 3, problem 3

At one college, the tuition for a full time student
is $8,000 per semester. It has been announced that the
tuition will be increased by 3% each year for the next 5 years.
Write a program with a loop that displays the projected semester
tuition amount for the next 5 years, and the total cost of 4
years' worth of tuition starting from now.
'''

def main():
    tuition = 8000.00
    total = 0

    print("Year\t", "Tuition per semester")

    for i in range(1,6):
        #Tuition increased by 3% each year for the next 5 years
        tuition += tuition*0.03
        #Displays tuition fee for each year
        print(i,'\t',format(tuition, '.2f'))

    total += (8240+8487.20+8741.82+9004.07)*2
    print("Total tuition in 4 years: $", format(total,\
          '.2f'),sep = '')

main()

'''
Output:
Year     Tuition per semester
1        8240.00
2        8487.20
3        8741.82
4        9004.07
5        9274.19
Total tuition in 4 years: $68946.18
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    tuition = 8000.00
    tuition_list = []
    total = 0

    for i in range(5):

        tuition += tuition*0.03
        tuition_list.append(tuition)

    for i, x in enumerate(tuition_list[:4]):
        print(f'Year {i+1}\tTuition ${round(x)}')

    print(f'Total for 4 years ${round(sum(tuition_list[:4]) * 2)}')


main()
```

Each tuition gets appended (added) to a list, so you end up with a list of 5 elements.

Then I iterate over the list with enumerate(). This lets me access each list item and also create an index number (0 - 5). I limit the list to 4 using list[:4].

I then use inline variables in a string just because that's how I like to do it. I sum the list, again limit it to the first 4 items, then times 2 as you had it.

Output:

```
>>> Year 1  Tuition $8240
>>> Year 2  Tuition $8487
>>> Year 3  Tuition $8742
>>> Year 4  Tuition $9004
>>> Total for 4 years $68946
```

EDIT:

In response to OPs comment.
You could assign the 4 tuition costs to variableslike so

```
def main():
    tuition = 8000.00
    tuition_list = []

    tuition_yr1 = tuition * 1.03
    tuition_yr2 = tuition_yr1 * 1.03
    tuition_yr3 = tuition_yr2 * 1.03
    tuition_yr4 = tuition_yr3 * 1.03

    total_cost_over_4yrs = (tuition_yr1 + tuition_yr2 + tuition_yr3 + tuition_yr4) * 2

    print('Year 1', tuition_yr1)
    print('Year 2', tuition_yr2)
    print('Year 3', tuition_yr3)
    print('Year 4', tuition_yr4)
    print('Total over 4 years', total_cost_over_4yrs)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I know this is probably the most efficient way to do it, but I have yet to learn about lists. Is there another way to do it? Perhaps using an if statement or something along the more basic stuff.

Comment: Sure, checkout my response, i added a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list to save the values for each year.
In this example element "i" of the list corresponds to year "i+1", since the list goes from 0 to 4

```
tuition = 8000.00
tuition_year = [tuition]
for i in range(1, 5):
    tuition_year.append(tuition_year[i-1] * 1.03)

total = sum(tuition_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tuition(base, inc, size):
    for x in range(size):
        base += base * inc
        yield base

print("Year\t", "Tuition per semester")
for i, x in eunmerate(tuition(8000, 0.03, 5)):
    print(i+1, "\t", format(x, ".2f"))

total = sum(tuition(8000, 0.03, 4))
print("Total tuition in 4 years: {.2f}".format(total))
```

Answer (score -1):

Also create an `empty list` before the for loop which stores the tution fees and then call the python `sum()` fucntion  which return the sum of all values in a list.

**Code Given**

```
    tutions=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        #Tuition increased by 3% each year for the next 5 years
        tuition += tuition*0.03
        #Displays tuition fee for each year
        print(i,'\t',format(tuition, '.2f'))
        tutions.append(tutions)

    total += sum(tutions)
    print("Total tuition in 4 years: $", format(total,\
          '.2f'),sep = '')
```