# Python: What is happening to my decimal places?

Tags: python, floating-point

Currently I am doing a coding lab for one of my classes and am stuck on this problem. I have to write a loop that displays tuition over 5 years. The tuition needs to be displayed exactly as the answer is and I am not sure why but the decimals on my last one are different so I keep getting the answer wrong.

```
tuition = 8000
for year in range(1, 6):
    interest = float(tuition * 0.03)
    tuition += interest
    if year <= 1:
        print(f"In {year} year, the tuition will be ${tuition}.")
    else:
        print(f"In {year} years, the tuition will be ${tuition}.")
```

[Picture of my output compared to what it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN3nr.png)

Comment: I suspect your instructor or whoever wrote the answer test cases made a mistake. 8240 * (1.03)^4 = 9274.1925944

Comment: Seems related requiring different output [Program for tuition per semester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994269/program-for-tuition-per-semester)

Comment: Can you show the instructions for the lab?

Comment: The problem is that they arrived at that answer by using `8000*(1.03)**5`. Due to floating point issues, the answer arrived using that approach gives `9274.192594400001`. Note, neither of these represent exactly the value, your approach yields `9274.19259439999950700439512729644775390625` and their approach yields `9274.192594400001325993798673152923583984375`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or by repeatedly multiplying with `1.03`. I suspect the instructions say how to do it, otherwise it would be silly to require their result exactly.

Comment: @KellyBundy true. True.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually, `8000 * 1.03**2` gives `8487.199999999999`, so that wouldn't match.

Comment: @KellyBundy Here is a picture of the [instructions](https://i.imgur.com/lqXQCTG.png).

Comment: Hmm, nothing about how to compute it and nothing about precision. Unless I'm overlooking some other difference (like if you were printing "years" instead of "year"), that's a bad question/judge by them. They should either say how to compute the exact numbers they happen to get with the way they chose, or accept close-enough numbers (especially since they're the ones with the less accurate result).

Comment: 0.03 is not an exact float.  All exact floats with a fractional part end with 5 as the last right-most non-zero digit.  Scale it by 100 to do the math without floats.